# pass form value into src url of iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have been driving myself crazy to try to do what seems so simple.  I have a form where i ask zip code.  I am using colorbox to popup a lightbox with an iframe after you input your zipcode.  I need to pass the zip code value from the form into the source URL of the iframe.  My form code looks like this:

```
<div class="form-zip-start">
    <p>Enter your zip code to begin your search:</p>
    <form id="submit" action="#" name="submit" method="post">
        <input name="zip" id="zip" type="text" value="" class="zip-start" />               
        <div class="form-submit"><a href="/form.htm" rel="zipformSubmit" class="zipformSubmit">Submit</a></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My js code looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ppc/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel=zipformSubmit]").click(function() { $("form#submit").submit(function(e) { 
        var zip = $('#zip').attr('value');  
        colorbox({href: "?zip=" + zip, iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600});
    });
    });
    });
</script>
```

the end result should be an iframe loaded like...src="/form.htm?zip=92108"

the 92108 value should be from the form input called 'zip'

I can't seem to get the zip code value to pass properly.  Can anyhow show me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use preventDefault() to prevent the browser from simply following the link, also you are putting your actions inside the submit event of your form, but you have no submit button, and you are not triggering the submit event, so that event never fires. In this case you don't need to submit the form, so you can simply make use of the link click event to open the iframe using the data entered in the form. Like so

```
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("a[rel=zipformSubmit]").click(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
             var zip = $('#zip').val();
alert("about to open colorbox with zipcopde " + zip);
            $.colorbox({href: "?zip=" + zip, iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600}); 
        }); 
        });  </script>
```

Note: some validation would be good `if (zip.length > 0) { }` etc

**Added after Comment:**

IN order to bring in your `$_GET['Source']` you should add a hidden form field:

```
    <div class="form-zip-start">
        <p>Enter your zip code to begin your search:</p>
        <form id="submit" action="#" name="submit" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='source' id='source' value='<?php echo $_GET['Source']; ?>' />
            <input name="zip" id="zip" type="text" value="" class="zip-start" />               
            <div class="form-submit"><a href="/form.htm" rel="zipformSubmit" class="zipformSubmit">Submit</a></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

then make the js:

```
<script> 
            $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("a[rel=zipformSubmit]").click(function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                 var zip = $('#zip').val();
                 var source = $('#source').val();
    alert("about to open colorbox with zipcopde " + zip);
                $.colorbox({href: "?source="+source+"&zip=" + zip, iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600}); 
            }); 
            });  </script>
```

Comment: thank you but when i try your code above, nothing happens when i click on the link with rel=zipformSubmit

Comment: Try that and you will find that the zip code will be in the alert, which means that the problem is in your call to colorbox. I have tried adding $. which should help, but I am rusty with colorbox, as I now use fancybox

Comment: i originally had the following in my href in the form  `<a href="/form.htm?source=<?php echo $_GET['source']; ?>" rel="zipformSubmit" class="zipformSubmit">Submit</a>`.  how can i also pull in this source param from the original url along with the zip from the form input?  thanks so much for your help!

Comment: add to answer now, please upvote my answer and select as correct

Comment: i added the following hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="source" value="blah" />` and updated the js code as you have above but changed the alert box to ` alert("this is source " + source);` and the source value is coming back as undefined.  any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: actually i think i got it, it has to be `<input type="hidden" name="source" id="source" value="blah" />`

Comment: what would i add to the js code so that the user can enter their zip code and hit enter to process in addition to being able to just click submit?

Answer (score 0):

trie this, i changed

```
var zip = $('#zip').attr("value");
```

with this

```
var zip = $('#zip').val();
```

JS code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ppc/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("a[rel=zipformSubmit]").click(function(){ 
            $("form#submit").submit(function(e) {
                var zip = $('#zip').val();
                colorbox({href: "?zip=" + zip, iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600});
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: But the form isn't submitting, it is being submitted via a link click, the submit event will not fire