# colorbox not sending url parameters

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to open a colorbox with an URL containing parameters (a serialized form), this is my code:

```
$('a.mapLink').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#currentSelection').serialize();
        alert($(this).attr('href') + "?" + data);
        $.colorbox({ href: $(this).attr('href') + "?" + data , iframe: true, width: '800px', height: '600px' });
});
```

the alert displays this:

```
/controller/action?Adults=2&Minors=0&StartingDate=2013-03-01&ReturningDate=2013-03-31
```

That's correct but then the parameters are not sent to the server by the colorbox, this is the console output:

```
XHR finished loading: "http://www.server.com/controller/action".
```

I don't know why the parameters are not being sent to the server I followed [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206931/pass-form-value-into-src-url-of-iframe-with-jquery) but I see no diferences from what I'm doing, please if anyone knows how to fix this I'd appreciate it.

If I open the console an put this:

```
$.colorbox({href:"/controller/action?Adults=2&Minors=0&StartingDate=2013-03-01&ReturningDate=2013-03-31", iframe:true, width:"800px", height:"600px"});
```

it works fine

PS I'm not using POST and AJAX because I'm loading a google map and it can be triky so I decided to use it as a iframe

Comment: look through the colorbox source and see if it manipulates the url

Comment: Instead of looking through the source, just check your document to see what the src of the iframe is. If it is correct you'll know the problem is not with the iframe, and if it is wrong you can double check to see what the issue may be with your formatting.

Comment: I realized that all the options are being ignored, if my anchor has an hfer="something.html" the colorbox opens that instead of the href defined in the object: $colorbox({href:'ignored.html', iframe:true}) and it opens as AJAX instead of iframe

Answer (score 0):

What happen if you try this?:

```
$('a.mapLink').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $('#currentSelection').serialize();
        var urlString = "" + $(this).attr('href') + "?" + data;
        alert(urlString);
        $.colorbox({ href: urlString , iframe: true, width: '800px', height: '600px' });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but even if I put a complete string in the href parameter it is ignored